# Scrolling two UITableViews together

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have a weird design case in which to implement I need to place two UITableViews on the same view. I would just use sections, but I need an index on the second table.

I'd like them to both scroll together like they were actually two sections of the same table view. Is this possible?

Here's a basic mockup illustrating why:

[image: mockup]

As far as I understand it, you cannot move the index. Also, when you add an index to a table, it appears over the entire tableview, not just one section.

If I have to implement this as two table views, they both need to scroll as if they were one. If it's possible to do this using sections, that's even better.

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by "index on the second table". I'm not convinced that a single `UITableView` will not suite your needs.

Comment: Could you please make your question more specific on what you are trying to do ? I am sure we can find a simpler solution that uses just 1 `UITableView` !

Answer (score 24):

**Update**

After seeing your update my old answer is not very good but I'll leave my previous answer for anyone else who wants it.

New answer - It depends how you want the tables sync'd.

If you know

1. Which cells are in the `top 5`
2. How tall each cell is
3. The offset the table view

Then you can calculate which cell is visible at the top of the `top 5` table. You can use this information to scroll the bottom table to the correct index.

---

**Old answer**

I'm with the other guys not sure why you would want to or if I am misinterpreting but it's pretty simple.

`UITableView` is a subclass of `UIScrollView` so you can set yourself as the `UITableViewDelegate` and override

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView;
{
    UITableView *slaveTable = nil;

    if (self.table1 == scrollView) {
        slaveTable = self.table2;
    } else if (self.table2 == scrollView) {
        slaveTable = self.table1;
    }

    [slaveTable setContentOffset:scrollView.contentOffset];
}
```

This gives me something that looks like this:

[image]

The top `UITableView` is `self.table1` and the bottom is `self.table2` if either table is scrolled the scrolling is mirrored in the other table.

Comment: It works for me to scroll tow parallel placed TableViews to scroll in unison

Comment: This worked until I needed to automatically scroll tableview A to some position, then tableview B would not scroll correctly to the right content offset.

Comment: Also, I'd get strange results with tableview B because the cells in tableview A would have different heights using autolayout. I don't think tableviews were designed to do this. Right now I'll have to find a working route, it looks like I just have to look somewhere else than tableviews. Anyone have any other suggestions? I guess I might look into using a uiscrollview and add everything to it. The problem there is memory issues if you need to include a lot of contents - which I will need to.

Answer (score 2):

in swift this code:

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    if tb_time1 == scrollView {
        tb_time2.contentOffset = tb_time1.contentOffset
    }else if tb_time2 == scrollView {
        tb_time1.contentOffset = tb_time2.contentOffset
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

From the mock-up it seems like this can be accomplished with a single `UITableView` with two sections.

Instead of maintaining two tableViews you could maintain two collections (one for each section). Then in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` choose the collection to use based on the section specified in the indexPath.

Comment: The index will appear over both sections, not just the second section.

Comment: I don't think I completely understand what you're trying to do. Please clarify with an example.

Comment: I'd like to have an index on the table, but only in the second section. As it is now, if I add an index, it appears where it appears (over the entire table). I only want indexing on the second section.

Comment: I think you can accomplish this with the section and row properties on indexPath.