# How to create a UI view with 2 scrolls in iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, tableview

I am a java developer and new to this iPhone programming so my question may seems little silly to the experts. But this is all what I have as of now.

I want to create a simple app in iPhone which is having 2 scroll views in a same window (i.e. same UI view). for a reference [here is the url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8334340/scrolling-two-uitableviews-together) where you can see actual view how it should look, here in my case i do not want the sync up thing that this person needed, I just need a single view having 2 table views on that.

Can any one explain a little approach and steps to follow up in Xcode, what kind of template i should choose in XCode - I am using iOS6 with Xcode 4.6(i know i am asking much details but please consider that i am java guy and new to this world )how I need to follow i mean like create 1 ui view then add 2 table view etc etc...

Answer (score 1):

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    UIScrollView  *scrollView1 = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 200)]; // set as per your requirement 
    [scrollView1 setContentSize:CGSizeMake( 320, 205 )];// set as per your requirement 
    [self.view addSubview:scrollView1];

UIScrollView  *scrollView2 = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 210, 320, 200)]; // set as per your requirement 
    [scrollView2 setContentSize:CGSizeMake( 320, 205 )];// set as per your requirement 
    [self.view addSubview:scrollView2];
}
```

Comment: Thanks for you very quick response, i try this way and got 2 views, but can't we achieve it using interface builder, because what i needed is it will be more easier for me to set other properties like border title size as well as one more thing i need is to display the table view cells in these 2 views which you created. Is there any template or control in IB can help this out? Thanks for the help again.