# Scroll second UITableView in line with second UITableView

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift

I have two table views set up side by side, and I need them to scroll at exactly the same time. So, when you scroll one, the other one will scroll at the same time.

I did some searching and I couldn't find any information, but I assume it must be possible somehow.

My table views are both connected to the same class and I differentiate between them like this:

```
if tableView == tableView1 {
    //
} else if tableView = tableView2 {
    //
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get set the `scrollView` delegate to self on both of your `tableView`'s `scrollViews`. And in `-scrollViewDidScroll`, take the `contentOffset` and set the other `scrollView`'s `contentOffset` to the same value.

Comment: The table views would wind up at the same position with your solution but they wouldn't scroll in sync with each other.

Comment: So would this scroll one in sync with the other? But not both?

Comment: @DuncanC they will. -scrollViewDidScroll will sync them up. Because both of them are synced up, it will always be in the same position relative to each other. Also since you set the delegate for both tableViews, you know how to compare which one is which, so you can move the other scrollView when this one is scrolled, and vice versa.

Comment: @DuncanC Of course, if the scrollViews don't have the same offset at the beginning, then this will make the other scrollView jump.

Comment: I haven't tried this, but it seems to me that the scrollViewDidScroll method is called once the scroll view STOPS scrolling. It doesn't tell you when it started, or how fast the user scrolled it. That's what the other calls about starting and ending dragging, and accelerating and decelerating are for.

Comment: @DuncanC no, scrollViewDidScroll is called for every scrollView movement. didEndDecelerating is the one that tells you when it stops scrolling.

Comment: Cool. That's simpler than I would have thought.

Answer (score 3):

Like Schemetrical said you should use scrollViewDidScroll.
see the first answer of this:
[Scrolling two UITableViews together](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8334340/scrolling-two-uitableviews-together?answertab=votes#tab-top)

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView;
{
    UITableView *slaveTable = nil;

    if (self.table1 == scrollView) {
        slaveTable = self.table2;
    } else if (self.table2 == scrollView) {
        slaveTable = self.table1;
    }

    [slaveTable setContentOffset:scrollView.contentOffset];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want them to scroll in prefect lock-step then this isn't a trivial problem. UITableView is a subclass of UIScrollview, so you could probably create a custom subclass of UITableView that overrode various UIScrollView methods and when something caused the table view to scroll, it would do the same thing to the other table view.

Edit: @Schemetrical's suggestion of using the scroll view delegate is cleaner than creating subclasses. You might have to monitor quite a few of the scroll view delegate methods and use them to match the behavior in the other scroll view.

### EDIT #2:

Apparently I'm wrong and scrollViewDidScroll is called for every change in the scroll view, so it's simpler than I thought to keep them synced.  I'm going to leave my answer for context even though I was wrong.